# React: Would it a better choice to use redux than context to pass a value from child to parent and share it with sibling components?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context

My react app structures like this (simplified)

```
<App> --> 
    need UserId information to conditional render something
    return (
     <Header/>
     <Contents/>
)
```

```
<Header> -->
   const login = () => retrieves an UserId after user login
   return (
      <Navbar etc/>
)
```

```
<Content> --> requires UserId information to do something
```

After user login in `<Header>` component, I need to pass it back to `<App>` as well as share it with `<Content>` component and others. 
As my react app has more than five sibling components which all need access to `userId` information, I think it might not be a wise choice pass the information one by one using `props`.  Would it be better to use `Redux` here because as far as I read, `Context` is for passing from parent to child not vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both `Context` and `Redux` to share data across components in react without using props.

There are 2 main things to consider when you choose between.

1. `Redux` updates states faster than `Context`

   If you need to access your states quickly, or if your states change too rapid, then it is more convenient to use Redux.
2. When you have too many `Contexts` you will have to manage different contexts across your app i.e. wrap different components with different contexts or wrap same component with too many contexts(I call it context hamburger, when the number of contexts grow it might get messy).

You can use both at the same time. There is no problem with that. For login information, `Context` is used more often, since you only login and logout once in a while.